# How to import the xml file into JTable in JAVA Swing?

Tags: java, xml, swing, user-interface, jtable

I want to import the xml file into JTable, create a table and show it to the user.I know how to read the file and display it on the console but I have no idea how to show it in a GUI. Can anybody give me some ideas?

I have written a file chooser:

```
public String fileChooser(){
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML file","xml");
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return fileName;
}
```

Parse XML Document:

```
public void readTheFile(String filePath){
    try {   
     File inputFile = new File(filePath);
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory 
        = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
     System.out.println("Root element :" 
        + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
     NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
     System.out.println("----------------------------");
     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" 
           + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           System.out.println("Student roll no : " 
              + eElement.getAttribute("rollno"));
           System.out.println("First Name : " 
              + eElement
              .getElementsByTagName("firstname")
              .item(0)
              .getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Last Name : " 
           + eElement
              .getElementsByTagName("lastname")
              .item(0)
              .getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Nick Name : " 
           + eElement
              .getElementsByTagName("nickname")
              .item(0)
              .getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Marks : " 
           + eElement
              .getElementsByTagName("marks")
              .item(0)
              .getTextContent());
        }
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

the JMenuItem-(open the file):

```
JMenuItem mnItemOpenFile = new JMenuItem("Open the file");
    mnItemOpenFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            readTheFile(fileChooser());

        }
    });
```

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
      <student rollno="393">
      <firstname>dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>kad</lastname>
      <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
      </student>
      <student rollno="493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
  <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
  <nickname>vinni</nickname>
  <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="593">
      <firstname>jasvir</firstname>
      <lastname>singn</lastname>
      <nickname>jazz</nickname>
      <marks>90</marks>
   </student>
   </class>
```

I want to show this in JTable：
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXhO5.png

When the user presses the "open the file",they can choose the XML file and the program will load a file automatically and put the data which are from the file into the JTable,like the image above.

How can I write this function?

Comment: What did you try ?  Try creating a `JFrame`  and add `JMenuItem` to it. Post the gui code when you have questions / problems.

Comment: You need to parse the XML-file and depending on it's structure / content you can either create objects from it or go through the XML-nodes and do stuff with them. For example use this: http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html

Comment: I have parsed the XML-file,please  check my code

Comment: I think you are almost there: At the points, where you use `System.out.println()` and then parse the node, you can use a method from the `JTable` called `setValueAt()`. With this you simply set what you are outputting now. See here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/TochangecellcontentsincodesetValueAtObjectvalueintrowintcolumnmethodofJTable.htm